# Long (500ms) Pulse Extender

Tags: switches, integrated-circuit, signal, pulse

I have an SPST momentary tactile switch and want the pulse, whatever length, to be extended to 500ms (unless of course the button is pressed for longer than 500ms but we can ignore that if we hold the pulse form the rising edge). I don't know if there is a single IC to hold a pulse like this or if I can do it with passive components like resistors and capacitors.

Comment: You want something called an edge-triggered monostable multivibrator.  The 74HC126 is such a beast, although it is not highly regarded.  To get reliable 500ms pulses, I'd recommend the smallest microcontroller you can find, and just a bit of code.  An ATTiny or PIC10 in a SOT-23 package will be several times smaller than the timing capacitor you'd need to go with an analog chip, totally aside from the fact that it'll be smaller than the analog chip itself.

Comment: What's your preference? You can do it with one mosfet, one BJT, a capacitor, a resistor, and a diode or two. Or you can do it with an MCU. How precise must the timing be? Do you want the duration to last half a second longer than the button is pressed? Or a half-second, regardless of how long?

Comment: Half a second regardless of how long however if it is pressed longer, it doesn't matter if the pulse is longer. I don't mind how accurate, but needs to be at least 500ms. Ideally I don't want to use a microcontroller since its a tiny part of an entirely analog circuit and would have to be duplicated which may become expensive. I don't mind whether its a mosfet transistor cap resistor or diode(s)

Comment: @TimWescott  I believe you were thinking of the '121 or '123.  '126 is a quad buffer.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist: Whups.  Thanks -- I didn't double-check before I spoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CMOS inverter, a diode , cap and resistor to discharge the cap slowly.

It's called a  monostable Multivibrator or 1 SHOT and there are many other ways to accomplish this.

But the typical IC's are state driven, while some are edge driven.
They may be re-triggerable or non-retriggerable and the latter is what you wanted.

The **LTC®6993-1** is a monostable multivibrator (also known as a “one-shot” pulse generator) with a programmable pulse width of **1µs to 33.6 seconds,** with the non-retrig option and rising edge option.

### Rev B

### Easy 0.6s with 6 in one IC

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feqrl3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[SIM LINK](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%20105.18789638808724%2050%205%2050%0A183%200%20160%2080%20160%200%200.5%201.66%203.33%205%200%0Ar%200%20160%200%2080%200%204700000%0Aw%20-64%2080%200%2080%200%0Aw%20-64%20160%200%20160%202%0As%20-64%20160%20-64%20208%200%201%20true%0Ag%20-64%20240%20-64%20272%200%0AR%20-64%2080%20-64%2064%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%2080%20160%2096%20160%200%0A403%2080%2080%20208%20144%200%207_1024_0_4354_0.0000762939453125_0.00009765625_0_2_7_3%0Ar%20-64%20208%20-64%20240%200%201000%0A403%20-240%2080%20-112%20144%200%203_1024_0_4354_5_0.00009765625_0_2_3_3%0Ac%20-64%2080%20-64%20160%200%201e-7%200.019414037860164157%0A)

Comment: Tony how could I set the time on the LTC®6993-1? On the data sheet it says just use a resistor between GDN and SET but how do I caculate the values for that?

Comment: Page 1 says tOUT = NDIV •RSET
50kΩ • 1µs, NDIV = 1, 8, 64,...,221

Comment: not gonna lie im not understanding a lot of that...

Comment: Why aren't you using the HC14's  schmitt triggers?  It does the same as a 555 here

Comment: Im not using any yet because I need to know how to use them.

Comment: Did you click on the switch yet? http://tinyurl.com/y8olwhwr  The invert threshold is 1/3 then 2/3 Vcc  for hysteresis

Comment: What? Does is work or not?

Comment: Of course it works

Comment: It does seem to stay on until pressed again?

Comment: The R pulls up in 0.6s to drive output low

Answer (score 0):

As much as it pains me to say this, a CMOS 555 will do exactly what you want.  The standard circuit will give a constant output pulse width for any input pulse shorter than the timeout period.  If the input still is low, the output will remain high until the input goes high; then the output will go low immediately.  Retriggers caused by switch bounce during the timing period are ignored.  The Micrel MIC1555 is in a 5-pin SOT-23 package.  1 chip, 1 R, 1 C (plus decoupling).

https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MIC1555

Comment: Could you possibly provide a small schematic or more component and pin details on how the 555 could be used?

Comment: oh no, not the 555.  Then you need to show him how to make it non-retriggerable.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist: the OP mentions in the comments to the question that he doesn't mind if it's longer if the switch is pressed longer -- so, presumably a retriggerable is OK.

Comment: Figure 3 in section 8.4.1 in [this datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc555.pdf).  You really can't lay claim to being an analog circuit designer unless you've designed some circuits with the 555.

Comment: **You can't really be an Analog Designer®** .... unless you know how to make 1-shots with a digital Schmitt Trigger equivalent to six (6) 555's  for even less cost.   ;) (lol)  I've never used a 555 in any product design.

Comment: Not to get into a pedantic semantic contest or anything, but a 555 is not retriggerable in the classic sense, because a trigger edge or event does not reset (discharge) the timing capacitor.  This is a good thing because the OP requirements do not permit retriggering.

Comment: OR make four flipflops with one ULN2803.

Comment: 615283 - the circuit and component equations are in the datasheet in the link.